# How to use sed with this complex expression of special chars and ips?

Tags: bash, sed

How to use `sed` to replace for example this expression:

```
connection = sqllite///keystone@10.10.10.51
```

with this expression

```
connection = mysql://keystoneUser:keystonePass@10.10.10.51/keystone
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use, for example:

```
echo "connection = sqllite///keystone@10.10.10.51" | \
sed "s/sqllite\/\/\/keystone@10.10.10.51/mysql:\/\/keystoneUser:keystonePass@10.10.10.51\/keystone/"
```